# CSS Make list-items totally responsive

Tags: html, css

I am facing a weird problem. I have an un-ordered list of images. List has 4 Items. I want to include it in responsive page and all I want is that all  items should have a 25% width and the list itself should span the width of whole screen.  Well it all sounds easy and straight-forward but for some odd reason I can't assign 25% width to the list-items and only three items accommodate in one line if I assign `width:25%`.

If I reduce the width to `24.4%` the items are in line. But then again weirdly when I resize browser one of the item goes into 2nd line.

I am using Google chrome. Here is the HTML:

```
<ul class="imgs">
        <li>aaaa</li>
        <li>bbbb</li>
        <li>cccc</li>
        <li>dddd</li>

        </ul>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.imgs {
width: 100%;
list-style: none;
margin: auto;
    padding:0px;
}
.imgs li {
width: 24.4%;
margin: 0px !important;
padding: 0px !important;
display: inline-block;
}
```

And here is the Fiddle Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/7HXw7/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WIth inline-bock elements, the browser will interpret the space between the li's as actual spaces and that's why your elements aren't lining up. If you just remove the space, it'll line up. See code:

```
<ul class="imgs"><li>aaaa</li><li>bbbb</li><li>cccc</li><li>dddd</li></ul>
```

Or the fiddle, here: http://jsfiddle.net/dgvc9/

Alternately, if you find this as annoying as would think you do, you can make the li's block elements and float them left.

See alternate fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Gxvd/

Comment: +1. But do you know the reason why it happens? I mean why browsers behave like this shouldn't it treat inline-blocks as blocks?

Comment: @Ahmar Inline blocks are inline blocks. Blocks are blocks.

Comment: Just as if you had an image tag along with some text in markup, the whitespace would be interpreted as spaces because an image tag is inline-block. You are making your li's the same type of element display in your example. This is the nature of inline-block display types.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding:

```
float: left;
```

to `.imgs li`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7HXw7/4/)